# Passing class as parameter in java function

Tags: java, json

I am trying to pass Java class as parameter in function, reason behind it it that I have several pojo classes for different APIs and I am trying to create a single parser utility for all the API URL and pojo class, I have tried with little or no success.

below is the code example -

```
   public class util {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        List<JsonGenMovies> jsongen = null;
        String url = "http://www.dishanywhere.com/radish/v20/dol/movies/carousels/featured.json?nkey=0e1345ee597cf280c8a2cde367b6b894";
        getMovieParser(jsongen, url);

        List<JsonGenShow> jsongenShow = null;
        String URL = "http://www.dishanywhere.com/radish/v20/dol/shows/carousels/featured.json";
        getShowParser(jsongenShow, URL);
    }

    public static String[] getMovieParser (List<JsonGenMovies> jsongen, String url ) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        URL jsonUrl = new URL(url);
        ObjectMapper objmapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsongen = objmapper.readValue(jsonUrl, new TypeReference<List<JsonGenMovies>>() {});
        String[] shows = new String [jsongen.size()]; 
        int i = 0;
        for(JsonGenMovies element : jsongen) {
            shows[i++]=element.getName();
        }
        for(int j =0; j<shows.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(shows[j]);
        }
        return shows;   
    }

    public static String[] getShowParser (List<JsonGen> jsongenShow, String URL ) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        URL jsonUrl = new URL(URL);
        ObjectMapper objmapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsongenShow = objmapper.readValue(jsonUrl, new TypeReference<List<JsonGen>>() {});
        String[] shows = new String [jsongenShow.size()]; 
        int i = 0;
        for(JsonGen element : jsongenShow) {
            shows[i++]=element.getName();
        }
        for(int j =0; j<shows.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(shows[j]);
        }
        return shows;   
    }
}
```

in the line -

```
jsongen = objmapper.readValue(jsonUrl, new TypeReference<List<JsonGen>>() {});
```

I still have `<List<JsonGen>>`a hard coded class name which I am trying to replace with arguments. please if you can help.

Please reply with little explanation, one liner might not be my thing.

Regards
Shek

Comment: Can you clarify _replace with arguments_?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, "replace with the arguments passed in call of the function" , so here  getParser(jsongen, URL); I am passing instance of "List<JsonGen> jsongen" , I want to replace <List<JsonGen>> too with parameter.

Comment: I still don't understand.

Comment: What's `JsonGen`? AFAICS you want to use `Class<T> clazz` as argument rather than passing a specific class, but I don't fully understand what you're doing in that code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza really sorry all the confusion I have created , I have edited the original question, I want to use same parser code for all the API URL and all the pojo classes I have , right now I am creating as many parser functions as pojo classes. in the updated example , I have two function parsing different URLs for separate pojo classes. I am looking something where I can have one function for all.

Comment: What about using `<T> and passing `Class<T>` as argument, along with your `List<T>` as argument as well? I cannot provide an specific example since I don't really follow your code.

Comment: Look into Spring's `RestTemplate`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis :) sorry again , I have updated the code, in the code I am creating two function for parsing two separate URLs, while calling these function I have to pass class instance as reference with url , I am trying to have one function which could parse separate URLs for separate pojo classes. in short I want one function for what I am trying to do.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza JsonGen and JsonGenMovies are pojo classes with all the getters and setters.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly you want to have one function instead of two or more.
You can do that with `generic type`

E.g

```
public static <T> String[] getParser(List<T> jsongen, String url) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
  URL jsonUrl = new URL(url);
  ObjectMapper objmapper = new ObjectMapper();
  jsongen = objmapper.readValue(jsonUrl, new TypeReference<List<T>>() {
  });

  String[] shows = new String[jsongen.size()];
  int i = 0;
  for (T element : jsongen) {
    shows[i++] = element.getName();
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < shows.length; j++) {
    System.out.println(shows[j]);
  }
  return shows;
 }
```

If both `JsonGenMovies` and `JsonGen` extends/implements an interface or class, E.g `JsonGenMovies extends Json` then you can do this :

```
public static <T extends Json> String[] getParser(List<T> jsongen, String url)
```

`T` is a generic type, it does not really exist but it will be replaced at runtime by Class used for `jsongen` arg.

For example in :

```
List<String> myList;
getParser(myList, "http://blablabla.blalb.com");
```

All `T` are replaced by `String`.

I hope this is what you are looking for.
you can found more explanation about generic type [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) with better explanation than mine.

EDIT:

If you want to keep your POJO pattern then you can try this (not sure it will works)

```
public static String[] getParser(List<?> jsongen, String url) throws Exception {
  URL jsonUrl = new URL(url);
  ObjectMapper objmapper = new ObjectMapper();
  jsongen = objmapper.readValue(jsonUrl, new TypeReference<List<?>>() {
  });
  String[] shows = new String[jsongen.size()];
  int i = 0;
  for (Object element : jsongen) {
    Method method = element.getClass().getMethod("getName");
    shows[i++] = (String) method.invoke(element);
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < shows.length; j++) {
    System.out.println(shows[j]);
  }

  return shows;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to write basically the same thing. I think this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Duffydake Thanks, it's is showing error at `code`shows[i++] = element.getName(); and implying to add a cast. to resolve it i had to do this `code`if (element instanceof JsonGenMovies ) {
    JsonGenMovies jgm = (JsonGenMovies) element;
    shows[i++]=jgm.getName(); which again makes it class specific function.  :'(

Comment: @Shek like i said, to be able to call getName() all Class must have this function and to do this, you can create an abstract class, a class or an interface, extends/implements class/interface in both of your objects and then do public static <T extends MyInterface> ...

Comment: @Duffydake ` List<JsonGen> jsongenShow = null;
  String url1 = "http://www.dishanywhere.com/radish/v20/dol/movies/carousels/featured.json?nkey=0e1345ee597cf280c8a2cde367b6b894";
     getParser(jsongen, url1);`  ** it's throwing an error**  _The method getParser(List<T>, String) in the type util is not applicable for the arguments (List<JsonGenMovies>, String)_

Comment: I answered your question and more. Moreover there is all you need in it. If you've got trouble with [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) then go learn how it works and if you've got another problem then ask a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Duffydake It's not polymorphism , you cannot have two different pojos called in an generic class, if you extend or implement with an interface the contract will breach and pojo class will ask you to add all the implemented methods and that will break the mapping of object,. thanks for your time.

Comment: @Shek ok, so i guess `TypeReference` come from a library. I'm not sure at all but maybe with reflection you can do it, otherwise i think you can't with POJO pattern.